# If you have multiple wonders do you get multiple special powers?

Tags: 7-wonders

In 7 Wonders some stages of building a wonder provide special powers.

For example stage of 2 of Olympia (side A) allows you to build one free structure per age. If you have built 2 wonders in this case can you build 2 free structures per age?

Comment: It sounds like you're either playing a variant where you get two game boards or you're incorrectly assuming that each wonder space on your board constitutes a separate wonder. Each space is a stage of the same wonder that can only be built once. The correct answer to your question depends entirely on which situation you are dealing with.

Answer (score 6):

**Each player has a single Wonder board, and each Wonder stage can only be built once.**

The [Quickstart rules](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/7WONDERS_QUICKRULES_US_COLOR.pdf) cover this on the first page under **Actions**, but it is also covered in the [main rules](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/7WONDERS_RULES_US_COLOR.pdf) under **Game Overview**, Clarifications.  You may only build the stages in order from left to right, and each stage can only be built once per game.

> **build a stage of their Wonder**(in the order given by the board, from left to right): the card is placed partially under the board, face down.
>
> 2.b. **Build a Stage of a Wonder** - [...] each stage can only built once per game. (page 5, main rules)

For example, if you have **The Lighthouse of Alexandria**, building the 3 stages of side (A) would give you 3VP, one Raw Material of your choice per build step, and 7VP in stage order. Building the 3 stages of side (B) would give you a Raw Material of your choice per build step, a Production Good of your choice per build step, and 7VP in stage order.
[image: Lighthouse of Alexandria]

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're seriously misinterpreting something because your question doesn't make any sense as stated.

The best guess I can make: You can only build each wonder stage once. You cannot build the same wonder stage multiple times to get multiple copies of its ability.

Answer (score -4):

When building multiple wonders special powers accumulate. So if you build Olympia's special power twice you get 2 free structures per age. However for other structures such as Halicarnassus when you build it's special ability you only get to use it in the age that you built it.

Comment: You can only build each wonder stage once.